# C# : XML Parsing : Group XML on a node and then subGroup underneath the same group

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Batch Id="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PurchaseOrders>
    <PurchaseOrder id="xx267681">
      <Header>
        <AccountNumber>999</AccountNumber>
        <ShipDate>2/10/2009</ShipDate>
      </Header>
      <PurchaseOrderDetails>
        <Item>
          <ItemNumber>yy235240</ItemNumber>
          <Quantity>200</Quantity>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <ItemNumber>yy336820</ItemNumber>
          <Quantity>3</Quantity>
        </Item>
      </PurchaseOrderDetails>

    </PurchaseOrder>
    <PurchaseOrder id="zz267456">
      <Header>
        <AccountNumber>123</AccountNumber>
        <ShipDate>2/10/2009</ShipDate>
      </Header>
      <PurchaseOrderDetails>
        <Item>
          <ItemNumber>nn235240</ItemNumber>
          <Quantity>200</Quantity>
        </Item>
      </PurchaseOrderDetails>
    </PurchaseOrder>
  </PurchaseOrders>
</Batch>
```

Attached above is the XML file I am trying to parse. My current C# code find all items in the XML file and assigns it against the PO#. But the recent XML file I got to know that there can be multiple PO# in the same XML file and hence I now need to find only those items matching to that PO#.
So in above example, PONumber with xx267681 has 2 items whereas 2nd PO has only item.

Here is what I tried so far.

```
        try
            { 
                ArrayList ItemsInFeed = new ArrayList();
                XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
                foreach (var node in xDoc.Descendants("PurchaseOrder"))
                {
                    poID = node.Attribute("id").Value;  
                }
                foreach (var node in xDoc.Descendants("Item"))
                {
                    Items itemRcd = new Items();
                    itemRcd.ItemNr = node.Descendants("ItemNumber")?.First().Value;
                    ItemsInFeed.Add(itemRcd);
                }

                if (ItemsInFeed.Count > 0)
                {
        // Do other logic based on the items linked to each PO#.
        // Issue found : So far each XML file has one PO#, but latest XML file received has more than PO# and underlying items.
        ItemsInFeed.Clear();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Catch exception here 
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
           XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

            var results = xDoc.Descendants("PurchaseOrder").Select(x => new
            {
                poID = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
                items = x.Descendants("Item").Select(y => new
                {
                    itemNumber = (string)y.Element("ItemNumber"),
                    quantity = (int)y.Element("Quantity")
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Marked as accepted answer.